# Unrecognized font family Segoe-Bold when trying to run react-native run-ios on iOS simulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Getting the following error.

[image]

Here giving the Info.plist also

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
    <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
    <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Feather.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
    <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
    <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
    <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    <string>Segoe-Bold.ttf</string>
    <string>Segoe-BoldItalic.ttf</string>
    <string>Segoe-Italic.ttf</string>
    <string>Segoe.ttf</string>
</array>
```

For iOS my fonts(only the last four fonts i.e Segoe-Bold.ttf etc) are at '`/iOS/MyProject/fonts/`' this folder. But for android the fonts are at '`/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/`' folder.

Tried almost all the solutions found at stack overflow or some other links.

Here I should mention that I also tried with the following Info.plist but didn't work.

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
    <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
    <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Feather.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
    <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
    <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
    <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    <string>fonts/Segoe-Bold.ttf</string>
    <string>fonts/Segoe-BoldItalic.ttf</string>
    <string>fonts/Segoe-Italic.ttf</string>
    <string>fonts/Segoe.ttf</string>
</array>
```

But no luck!

Comment: Here I should mention that my react-native versions are: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.64.0

Comment: Have you tried `react-native link` ?

Comment: `postscriptname` should be used while using the icons in react native IOS

Comment: Try `fontFamily: "Segoe Bold"`. I had a similar problem with a custom font and this is how I fixed it.

Comment: Yes I tried with `react-native link` though in latest version it's not needed anymore. Pod install does the work for resource linking.

Comment: From Font Book app I got the Postscript name of the font is `SegoeUI-Bold` which I used in my code.  I also put the name in my `info.plist` file. But no luck! This time error becomes `Unrecognized font family SegoeUI-Bold`